# How to access the two key objects used in reduceByKey and combineByKey?

Tags: apache-spark

reduceByKey and combineByKey use Function2 to aggregate the counts of the same key.  Since Function2 passes only the current count of the keys, how do you access the actual two key objects used with reduceByKey and combineByKey ?

Comment: To clarify, this question is not about accessing arbitrary keys in the RDD. It is about accessing matching keys when RDD is processed by reduceByKey and combineByKey.  For instance, the RDD has 4 key/vaklue pairs. Two pairs have the same key of "A1", and the other two pairs have the same key of "B1".  In reduceByKey method via Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> (), it passes only in the values of the matching keys.  How do you access the actual objects of the matching key "A1" in this example ?

Answer (score 0):

Combine both keys in a **Tuple2** then you can easily perform reduceByKey and combineByKey

Here is the example

```
JavaRDD<Tuple3<String,String,Integer>> data = { .... };
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer> map = data.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple3<String,String,Integer>, Tuple2<String,String>, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer> call(Tuple3<String, String, Integer> t) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer>(new Tuple2<String, String>(t._1(),t._2()),t._3());
    }
});

map.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
        return v1+v2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Per clarification above, this question is  about accessing matching keys when RDD is processed by reduceByKey and combineByKey.. The JavaPairRDD already exists with a set of key/value pairs where some pairs have matching keys.  In reduceByKey and combineByKey methods via Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> (), they pass only in the values of the matching keys. How do you access the actual key objects with the matching key "A1" in this example ?

Comment: Use **lookup** function of JavaPairRDD like `pairRdd.lookup(key);` to get values according to key.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Thanks, Kaushal and Justin, for your previous responses.